# Kendo UI Grid and external service JSON binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have existing rest service and I am trying to show return values in Kendo Grid.

The return structure:

```
[{"Form":"xxx","Revision":x,"Status":"xxx"}]
```

I am using Razor syntax, so I created Grid like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<FormViewModel>()
      .Name("form-list")
      .AutoBind(false)
      .Columns(columns =>
          { 
              columns.Bound(m => m.Form).Title("Name");
              columns.Bound(m => m.Revision).Title("Revision");
          })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Read(read => read.Url(string.Format("{0}/{1}", Html.WebApiBaseUrl(), "Forms")).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
                                    .Model(model =>
                                        {
                                            model.Id(m => m.Form);
                                            model.Field(m => m.Revision);
                                        })
                                    .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))))
```

But my Grid cannot bind to the DataSource. As I understood Kendo required `ToDataSourceResult()` method call in order to perform correct JSON formating. But is it possible to do it directly from the client side?

Controller:

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetFormList()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean that the grid just doesn't display at all or it displays the axis and no points?

Comment: Also could you post the code of your controller's action?

Comment: I mean that grid doesn't display any data. It displays axis. The grid is empty. Controller is empty, but I will include it into the question, it just returns the view.

Comment: Just to clarify I am using external service, so Kendo grid is querying external service, my controller just returns the view.

Comment: Ok, I meant the "Forms" action.  But if that is an external service then don't worry.  I really wanted to check that it was compatible; does it accept GET requests.  Are you able to use something like Fiddler to check that it is really sending you the response you expected?

Comment: It looks like you are making a cross-site request for json. This might be blocked.  You perhaps need to use jsonp.

Comment: Service returns me correct JSON, so there are no blockers with that. I posted returned structure in the question, the problem is that I cannot bind my grid to it.

Comment: The grid probably uses XHR, which does not allow cross-domain JSON, only JSONP.

Comment: not sure I understand you, what should I change in my Grid definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work with Razor, but I was able to resolve the issue. So I create my grid like this:

```
<div id="form-list-view" class="k-content">
    <div id="form-list-grid"></div>
</div>

var formListDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   transport: {
       read: {
           url: "@Url.Content(string.Format("{0}/{1}", Html.WebApiBaseUrl(), "Forms"))",
           dataType: "json"
       }
   },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Form",
            fields: {
                Form: { type: "string" },
                Revision: { type: "number" },
                Status: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
   pageSize: 10
});

$("#form-list-grid").kendoGrid({
    autoBind: false,
    dataSource: formListDataSource,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "Form",
            title: "Name"
        },
        {
            field: "Revision",
            title: "Revision"
        },
        {
            field: "Status",
            title: "Status"
        }
    ]
});
```

Now I have expected behavior and my Grid correctly bind to the returned data.